# When android creates Sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Just want to know the moment database is created and checked for upgrade.
I dont call create database manualy and leave it to `SQLiteOpenHelper`. But I dont know, when and how clasees that extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` are called. Is it before Application `onCreate()` or after?

Comment: It's inside the DataBase Helper's `onCreate()` (which may also be called in `onUpgrade()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases for an application are created when you create them. Specifically when the application is installed it calls `onCreate()`.

You can read more here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Read the documentation @
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)

### Excerpt

```
public abstract void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)

Added in API level 1
Called when the database is created for the first time. This is where the creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should happen.

Parameters
db  The database.
```

Comment: I dont call create database manually. In that article, I dont see information when db is created by system.

Comment: A database has to be created by someone, WHAT database are you referring to?

Comment: I am using sqlite database and leave creation, upgrade etc. to `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: Read the documentation. Also add logs to figure out how they are called.

Answer (score 0):

It's crated when you make call to `SQLiteOpenHelper::getReadableDatabase` or `SQLiteOpenHelper::getWritableDatabase`.

Just check the docs, it's there:

[SQLiteOpenHelper::SQLiteOpenHelper(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int))

> Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This method always returns very quickly. The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() is called.

Comment: Or when you call `openOrCreateDatabase()`